# MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED and synchronization

Tags: fortran, mpi, mpi-rma

I try to do a mpi shared memory example , but every time i get some weird value.

It's a 1D stencil, just doing the sum of elements at position i-1,i and i+1

I'm running this program on 2 node of 32 MPI process and with the domain size nx=64, the domain of each rank has only 1 element.
I do the exchange between node with MPI_SENDRECEIVE with ghost cells

```
program mpishared
  USE MPI_F08
  use ISO_C_BINDING
  implicit none
  integer :: rank, rankNode, rankW, rankE
  integer :: nbp, nbNode
  integer :: key
  TYPE(MPI_Comm) :: commNode ! shared node
  integer :: nx ! area global
  integer :: sx,ex ! area local
  integer :: rsx,rex ! real bound of local array with halo
  integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: size
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: baseptr
  TYPE(MPI_Win) :: win
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
  real(kind=dp), dimension(:), contiguous, pointer :: ushared
  real(kind=dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: u
  integer :: iterx,iter,iterp

  !! Init MPI
  CALL MPI_INIT()

  !! Info WORLD
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nbp)

  ! Comm 4 Node
  key = 0
  CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT_TYPE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED,key,MPI_INFO_NULL,commNode)
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(commNode, rankNode)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(commNode, nbNode)
  ! Neighbours
  rankW = rank-1
  rankE = rank+1
  if (rank == 0) rankW=MPI_PROC_NULL
  if (rank == nbp-1) rankE=MPI_PROC_NULL

  ! Size of global domain
  nx = 64

  ! Size of local domain
  sx = 1+(rank*nx)/nbp
  ex = ((rank+1)*nx)/nbp
  rsx = sx ! real size only different for first
  rex = ex ! and last rank in node
  if (rankNode == 0) rsx = rsx-1
  if (rankNode == nbNode-1) rex=rex+1

  ! Allocate Shared domain
  size = (rex-rsx+1)
  allocate(u(rex-rsx+1))
  CALL MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED(size,1,MPI_INFO_NULL,commNode,baseptr,win)
  CALL C_F_POINTER(baseptr,ushared)

  ! Init local domain
  do iterx=1,rex-rsx+1
    u(iterx) = 0.0_dp
  end do
  if (rank == nbp-1) then
    u(rex-rsx+1) = rex
  end if
  if (rank == 0) then
    u(1) = -1.0_dp
  end if

  ! Main Loop
  CALL MPI_WIN_LOCK_ALL(0,win)
  do iter=1,10

    ! Update sharedold
    do iterx=1,rex-rsx+1
      ushared(iterx)=u(iterx)
    end do
    ! Update bound between node
    if (rankNode == 0) then
      CALL MPI_SENDRECV(ushared(2),nx,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,rankW,100, &
                        ushared(1),nx,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,rankW,100,&
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE)
    end if
    if (rankNode == nbNode-1) then
      CALL MPI_SENDRECV(ushared(ex-rsx+1),nx,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,rankE,100, &
                        ushared(rex-rsx+1),nx,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,rankE,100,&
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE)
    end if

    call MPI_WIN_SYNC(win)
    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD)

    ! Compute
    do iterx=sx-rsx+1,ex-rsx+1
      u(iterx)=(ushared(iterx-1)+ushared(iterx)+ushared(iterx+1))/3.0_dp
      !print *, rank, iterx, u(iterx), ushared(iterx-1), ushared(iterx), ushared(iterx+1)
    end do

    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD)
  end do
  call MPI_WIN_UNLOCK_ALL(win)

  do iterp=0, nbp-1
    if (iterp == rank) then
      do iterx=1,rex-rsx+1
        print * , iter,"u", rank, iterx, u(iterx)
      end do
    end if
    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD)
  end do

  CALL MPI_FINALIZE()
end program
```

The value after a lot of iterations must be equal to the rank

But when i'm running it, wrong value start to appear (like -6.018996517484083E+196 )

Since i'm new to MPI RMA, i don't know if it's a bug of the MPI implementation i use or if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Your code is quite big, can you reduce it or at least point is to the line of code where those valuese arise? Yu did try some debugging prints, didn't you?

Comment: It's hard to reduce it but the problem arise on the compute part some ushared value are wrong.

Comment: it seems you assume how MPI tasks will be numbered (e.g. pack a node first). If your `mpirun` or resource manager does not guarantee this, then you can end up in a deadlock or incorrect results.

Comment: It's true. it is not a problem because i know that my mpirun scatter the MPI tasks in order.